# Отправка email с gmail-сервера в ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail

Ребят, доброго времени суток, пытаюсь вот сделать восстановление пароля через отправку письма на мыло. Вот кот

```
// MailMessage class is present is System.Net.Mail namespace
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("purityperfection333@gmail.com", ToEmail);


// StringBuilder class is present in System.Text namespace
StringBuilder sbEmailBody = new StringBuilder();
sbEmailBody.Append("Уважаемый " + UserName + ",<br/><br/>");
sbEmailBody.Append("Пожалуйста, нажмите на ссылку, чтобы ввести новый пароль");
sbEmailBody.Append("<br/>"); sbEmailBody.Append("http://localhost/WebApplication1/Registration/ChangePassword.aspx?uid=" + UniqueId);
sbEmailBody.Append("<br/><br/>");
sbEmailBody.Append("<b>Администрация херсонского автосервиса</b>");

mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

mailMessage.Body = sbEmailBody.ToString();
mailMessage.Subject = "Смена пароля";
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("purityperfection333@gmail.com", "пароль");

smtpClient.EnableSsl = true; 
smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

Выдаёт:

> Серверу SMTP требовалось защищенное соединение, или подлинность клиента не была установлена.
>
> Ответ сервера: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at*

Ругаясь на последнюю строку. На purityperfection333@gmail.com пришло сообщение, что была заблокирована попытка входа. Что исправить ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Скорей всего, у вас включена двухфакторная авторизация. Эта опция сейчас включена по умолчанию у всех новых пользователей.

Если вам не особо важна безопасность вашего аккаунта(вы уверенны, что никто не украдет пароль из вашего кода) - [создайте пароль приложения](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords), и используйте в коде именно его.

В случае, если безопасность важна, либо рассылка будет вестись от имен множества пользователей(приемущественно ваших клиентов) - посмотрите в сторону [OAuth-авторизации](https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol).

OAuth позволяет сильно ограничить права приложения. В частности, можно дать приложению право только отправлять почтовые сообщения и ничего более - ни доступа к другим сервисам Google, ни просмотра почтовых сообщений, ничего.  Так-же появляется возможность использовать RESTful API, позволяющий вообще обойтись без использования SMTP-сервера.

---

**Обновлено**:

Как оказалось, с середины 2014 года, Google объявили [все приложения использующие авторизацию по логину и паролю "ненадежными"](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.ru/2015/09/block-access-to-less-secure_15.html), и на всех учетных записях запретили по умолчанию вход таких приложений. В свою очередь "надежными" считаются только приложения использующие OAuth-авторизацию.

Для тех пользователей, у которых включена двухфакторная авторизация, их использование осталось возможно по паролю приложения.

А у пользователей, у которых двухфакторная авторизация включена не была, добавили [опцию разрешающую такие приложения использовать](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps), отключенную по умолчанию.

Comment: Спасибо за версию. В аккаунте написано, что "Двухэтапная аутентификация" отключена, а опция пароли приложений не доступна на моём аккаунте=\

Comment: @eXPerience, довольно странно. Внешне никаких проблем других не вижу. Попробую ваш код у себя, да отпишусь.

Comment: Я настроил двухэтапную аутентификацию и создал пароль приложения. Вписал его в код и он сработал без ошибок. Жду появления письма в ящике...

Comment: Заработало таки) Плюсую ваш ответ=)

Comment: @eXPerience, добавил обновление в свой ответ, с описанием причины почему действительно не работало. Откровенно говоря, до этого не знал. Честь и хвала Google - они действительно борются за безопасность пользователей, пусть и довольно жесткими мерами.